# Deploying a Silverlight browser application update manually

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, web

We have a Silverlight application. The data required for normal and even high load is quite low. The problem is with the deployment of updates. Updates can be quite big 1 Meg - 2 Meg or even much larger if we upgrade our third party libraries with a release.

Some of our clients have very slow lines (64k) to the server (it is not a public site). These lines are sufficient for handling quite a few users under the normal operation of the software but are totally insufficient for updates.

My question is this. How would we create an installation for a Silverlight in browser application that can be deployed either by running an installation of some sort or through domain policy? We can limit the browsers supported by the application because it is a controlled environment.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to achieve what you want. It may be possible if you choose to convert your app to an Out-of-Browser application, but I am not sure of that either.

Comment: Unfortunately an out of browser application is not an option as that would require quite a few modifications.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to come up with a manual strategy for how to best handle the updates. Perhaps you can come to an agreement with your clients on exactly when you will publish the updates so they can, for example, start the application, initialize the update and then go to lunch. Crap solution, I know, but maybe it will at least improve the situation. It is always more annoying to have to wait for an update if you are planning to do something important. At least you could alleviate that particular grievance by planning the updates ahead of time and let everyone know the schedule.

Comment: We have looked at this approach but a full installation takes well over 10 minutes on a 64k leased line which causes all sorts of problems (timeouts, etc). We can comfortably run 10 users in the same environment as long as we don't release updates or install new stations :(

Comment: I think that any web based tech would be wrong in this case, with a shared 64k line. Have you considered migrating the app to WPF? Then one person could download the update, put it on the internal network and everybody else could pick it up from there. This is of course assuming that your users only use Windows. And even if you can it will be a major undertaking.

Comment: I have upranked one of your comments. Thanks for your help. I found it best to re-look at the whole approach I was taking. I ended up changing the URL for the download rather than installing at the individual sites. This raises cross domain issues but at least solves the problem. Basically we point to a different URL for these specific clients so they download the CAB file from their own server instead of from the central server.

Comment: CAB file? You mean XAP, right?

Comment: Yes, XAP. It's been a long day :)

Comment: :) Just wanted to make sure I had not totally misunderstood your original question.